# An operator with integer eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

As is well-known, number operator $N=a^{\dagger}a$ with the commutation relation $[a,a^{\dagger}]=1$ has non-negative integer eigenvalues. I am looking for a similar expression for an operator ($A(a^{\dagger},a)$) which includes all integers, is there such an operator ? I don't like to impose  a naive guess such as $A|n\rangle =n|n\rangle,~~n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You can construct one by setting $A:=\sum\limits_{z\in \mathbb Z} z\, |n(z)\rangle\langle n(z)|$, where $n(z)$ is your favorite bijection from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$.

Comment: ohhh, thanks for these clever constructions, but are these of the form $A|n\rangle =n|n\rangle$? It satisfies $A|n(z_1)\rangle =z_1|n(z_1)\rangle$.

Comment: We may rename the basis to transform the construction to the desired form.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you were looking for an operator with the same eigenbasis as $$ but with integers instead of natural numbers as eigenvalues. Any $$ of the form above is such an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments amply answered your question, but if you want something illustrative, consider the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) on natural numbers including  zero,
$$
 \lceil n/2 \rceil=\min \{m\in\mathbb{N}_0\mid m\ge n/2 \}, 
$$
mapping *n* = 0,1,2,3,4,5,... to *m*= 0,1,1,2,2,3,... and grade it by
$$
A= (-)^N \lceil N/2   \rceil,
$$
whose eigenvalues are 0, -1,1,-2,2,-3,... It's best if you relabel your basis.